# How can I serve a wsgi app on demand?

Tags: python, wsgi

I have a small server on which I host the wsgi applications I write. This server does not have a lot of ram, and the applications are not frequently used and rarely more than one at once.

Is there a way to configure the server so that the applications are only started when they are needed (when I try to connect on the socket they're served on), somewhat like inetd does ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on the server software you use.

if you use nginx + uwsgi for example, you can configure the uwsgi workers to only be created on requests and get destroyed after a certain amount of inactivity.

http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Doc

look for "idle" "cheap" "cheaper"

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for. To uwsgi, then !